# Xamarin.Forms MemoryLeak analysis, view is not garbage collected, but viewmodel is

Tags: xamarin.forms, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I'm trying understand what causes a memory leak in my application.
Running a memory profiler I can see the LibraryPublicationView is not garbage collected, whereas the corresponding LibraryPublicationViewModel is.

My ViewModels don't reference the views, and the view also does not have any code behind logic, and is bound to the viewmodel.
I'm unsure how to approach this.

There is a second "thing" that is also increasing in count. It seems to be the datatemplate of a collecionview that I'm updating in this scenario (that contains the LibraryPublicationView). Because of the weird suffix I am unsure what to think of this.

The memory leak happens as I update the bound properties of ItemsSource and ItemsLayout

```
          <CollectionView 
                
                x:Name="MainCollectionView"
                ItemsSource="{Binding GroupedPublications}" 
                Grid.Row="1"  
                IsGrouped="True"
                FlowDirection="{Binding MyFlowDirection}"
                ItemsLayout="{Binding CollectionViewItemsLayout}"                    
                Margin="10,0,10,0" 
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never"                    
                SelectionMode="None"
                >                    
                <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewModels:GroupedPublicationViewModel">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="0" Padding="0" FontSize="Large"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <viewModels:LibraryPublicationView></viewModels:LibraryPublicationView>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Could it be that your NavigationPage/Shell still has a reference of the View and its not letting go of it which causes the ViewModel(not referenced anymore) to be GC'd but doesn't let your View get GC'd?

Comment: Also, is your CollectionView reusing its cells? What's your Sizing Strategy, What's your collection view loading strategy if you have a huge pile of items to load...

Comment: @FreakyAli I added some code. When the view is resized I recalculate the amount of columns, and refresh the items in the collection so some groups don't overflow onto the next line. 
The page that is referenced by the NavPage / shell is not refreshed but only resized. And I'm not actively setting any cell management

Comment: A similar issue [[Bug] [UWP] Memory Leak When Changing the ItemsSource on a CollectionView
](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/13928).

Comment: I created a sample project that reproduces the problem and submitted it to MS support: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/XamarinForms-UWP-CollectionView-Memory/10319497

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your response. Here is some doc that might be useful: [Cross-Platform Performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/deploy-test/memory-perf-best-practices), [SGen Garbage Collector and Profiling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/profiler/?tabs=windows#sgen-garbage-collector-and-profiling)